# Storing values in a database via AJAX not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this function which uses ajax, but this function doesn't work. I tried a lot, but I'm not able to figure out where the problem is. I am trying to create an alert, when the user inserts a duplicate entry into the database using a check-box selection.

```
<script>    
    function func(e,eid,emprid) {
       if(document.getElementById(e).checked){
          var dataString = 'eid=' + eid + '&emprid='+emprid;
          $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url: "mylistcheck.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(result){
                if(result!='0') {
                   modal.open({content: "<span style=\"color:red\" ><h2>You have already selected  candidate </h2></span>"});
                   document.getElementById(e).checked=false;
                }
             }
          });
       } 
    }
</script>
```

`mylistcheck.php` looks like this:

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
    $eid=$_POST['eid'];
    $emprid=$_POST['emprid'];

    $sqlchecklist="SELECT * FROM selected_candidate WHERE eid='{$eid}' AND rid='{$emprid}' ";
    $checklistres=mysql_query($sqlchecklist);
    $list_check=mysql_num_rows($checklistres);
    echo "numrows listcheck".$list_check;
    if($list_check>0) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

The check-box code is like this:

```
echo "<td><input id=\"select_candi{$i}\" onclick=\"javascript:func(this.id,{$data_set['eid']},{$emprid})\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_candi[]\" value=\"{$data_set['eid']},{$emprid}\"/></td>";
```

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you to choose. If you care to learn, here is good [PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Do u receive any error? check in error console

Comment: no i don't receive any errors,can you please tell how can i check it in error console as i am not so expert in php

Comment: Did you try calling the PHP script without AJAX, but rather with a normal POST form? This should give you an idea whether your problem is with PHP or with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have

```
echo "eid".$eid;
$emprid=$_POST['emprid'];
echo "rid".$emprid;
```

Since you are already echoing the result your ajax functie will never be just '0'. Its always something like `eid{value}rid{value}0` or `eid{value}rid{value}1`

Also switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for security reasons. Also check the values of `$eid` and `$rid` to match what you expect. Your code is vulnerable for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

In your script code you have `onclick="javascript:func(...)"`. `onclick` is already a javascript function, so you dont need the `javascript:`

Comment: i have commented them ,i have echoed them just to checkout where i have problem

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a **POST** request but the data is sent in **GET** form - i.e a string. You need to send it as an object instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "mylistcheck.php",
    data: {"eid":eid,
           "emprid":emprid}, // send an object
    success: function(result){
if(result!='0')
{
modal.open({content: "<span style=\"color:red\" ><h2>You have already selected  candidate </h2></span>"});
document.getElementById(e).checked=false;
}
}
});
```

Comment: yes i tried as you suggested but not working ,and even not getting any error

Comment: that is because you have other errors that needs be addressed. Look at @Hugo Delsing's answer

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you add `console.log(result)` in the beginning of your ajax `success` func. This will show you the returned data, which would make debugging much easier